# Error creating Vulkan instance when using layers

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm learning to use vulkan, when I don't use layers passing the parameter as `nullptr` the instance is created without errors, if not, the following error occurs at `vkCreateInstance`:

> (vulkan-1.dll) Access violation reading location `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

There is my code:

```
bool IEVkRenderer::CreateInstance()
    {
        ...
        std::vector<const char*> extensions;
        extensions.push_back("VK_KHR_surface");

        if (enableValidationLayers)
            extensions.push_back("VK_EXT_debug_report");

        extensions.push_back("VK_KHR_win32_surface");

        VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo;
        createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
        createInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
        createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
        createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();

        if (enableValidationLayers) {

            std::vector<const char*> layers;
            layers.push_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation");

            if (!CheckValidationLayersSupport(layers)) {
                lError("VK Renderer", "Validation layer not supported");
                return false;
            }

            createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(layers.size());
            createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = layers.data();

        }else {

            createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
            createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;

        }

        if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &m_Instance) != VK_SUCCESS)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post images of vital error messages and code. Copy and paste the actual text of those messages.

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe you didn't pay attention but it is written below the image

Comment: @IvesTI Yea, avoid using images of IDE in general. We are very strict about these things at StackOverflow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using memory past `delete`:

```
if (enableValidationLayers) {
    std::vector<const char*> layers;
    createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = layers.data();
}
vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &m_Instance)
```

Furthermore, your `createInfo.flags` is uninitialized value, which is invalid usage. Per spec it must be `0`. The established practice when using C bindings of Vulkan in C++ is to preinitialize the struct like so:

```
VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
```

Comment: Well, as I read the documentation from Vulkan it says that flags are reserved for future use, so I didnt initialize

Comment: @IvesTI Not initializing in C\C++ means random value. When the future use becomes present use, your random value would colide with it. Generally, Vulkan requires you to use only the flag bits that are defined by the Vulkan version + extensions you have enabled. If there are no such bits, that means `0` must be used. Anyway, your immediate problem is probably the use of the `std::vector` after it goes out of scope; that should fix your crash.